# Type System library

Tags: go, compiler

I would like some reviews of my Type system library in Golang that I am building for a compiler project.

Here are external links to the versioned source files,

- [types.go](https://github.com/Spriithy/virt/blob/master/comp/types.go)
- [builtins.go](https://github.com/Spriithy/virt/blob/master/comp/builtins.go)

The first file:

```
// types.go
package virt

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

// The Type interface is responsible for providing a uniform base for
// all subsequent types of the type system
type Type interface {
    // Size is used to get the size (in bytes) of the given type
    Size() int

    // TypeString returns the bare type representation
    TypeString() string

    // Kind returns the kind of the type (ie. Unit, Pointer, ...)
    Kind() TypeKind

    // Id returns the ID of the given type. A type's ID is bound to the underlying
    // type(s) rather than the type itself. This means that a type alias and its
    // source share the same TypeID.
    // This also implies that two structs that have the same memory layout share
    // the same TypeID.
    Id() TypeID

    // Equals determines whether two given types are the same or not.
    // Two types are equal should their TypeString be the same
    Equals(Type) bool

    fmt.Stringer
}

// UnitType represents the absence of type (typeless)
type UnitType struct{}

// UndefinedType represents the type of undefined values/symbols
type UndefinedType struct{}

// TypeAlias is simply used to create type aliases
type TypeAlias struct {
    // The name of the alias
    Name string

    // The aliased type
    Of Type
}

// BaseType represents primitive types such comp integers and floats
type BaseType struct {
    Alias string

    // Which base type (hear primitive) is concerned
    Which TypeID
}

// PointerType represents all types that are pointers to other types
type PointerType struct {
    Alias string

    // The Type pointed to by the PointerType
    To Type
}

// ArrayType represents all types of fixed-length
type ArrayType struct {
    Alias     string
    ElemCount int

    // The type of the elements held by such an array
    Of Type
}

// A StructType represents struct-like data structure
type StructType struct {
    Alias string

    // The Fields listed in the struct type
    Fields []Type
}

// An EnumType represents type enumerations
type EnumType struct {
    Alias string

    // The Entries (named) of the enum type
    Entries map[string]struct{}
}

// A FunctionType holds the signature of a function
type FunctionType struct {
    Alias string

    // The return type of a function type
    Returns Type

    // The arguments of a function type
    Args []Type
}

// Compile-time check
var (
    _ Type = (*UnitType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*UndefinedType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*TypeAlias)(nil)
    _ Type = (*BaseType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*PointerType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*ArrayType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*StructType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*EnumType)(nil)
    _ Type = (*FunctionType)(nil)
)

// TypeKind represents the type class of a type
type TypeKind = int

const (
    UnitKind = iota
    UndefinedKind
    BasicKind
    PointerKind
    ArrayKind
    StructKind
    EnumKind
    FunctionKind
)

// TypeID is used to hold hashes of types to identify them
type TypeID = uint64

// hash hashes a string using the java.lang.String.hashCode method
func hash(str string) TypeID {
    var hash TypeID = 7

    for _, c := range str {
        hash = hash*31 + TypeID(c)
    }

    return hash
}

// These values are used to identify builtin types
const (
    u8typeID TypeID = iota
    u16typeID
    u32typeID
    u64typeID
    i8typeID
    i16typeID
    i32typeID
    i64typeID
    f64typeID
    f32typeID
)

const (
    unitTypeString     = "unit"
    undefTypeString    = "undef"
    funcTypeArrow      = "->"
    nilTypeReplacement = "%!(nil)"
)


/*** UnitType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *UnitType) Size() int {
    return 0
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *UnitType) TypeString() string {
    return unitTypeString
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *UnitType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return UnitKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *UnitType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *UnitType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    return other != nil && other.Kind() == UnitKind
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *UnitType) String() string {
    return unitTypeString
}

/*** UndefinedType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *UndefinedType) Size() int {
    return 0
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *UndefinedType) TypeString() string {
    return undefTypeString
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *UndefinedType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return UndefinedKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *UndefinedType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *UndefinedType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    return other != nil && other.Kind() == UndefinedKind
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *UndefinedType) String() string {
    return undefTypeString
}

/*** TypeAlias implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *TypeAlias) Size() int {
    if t.Of == nil {
        return 0
    }

    return t.Of.Size()
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *TypeAlias) TypeString() string {
    switch t.Name {
    case "":
        if t.Of == nil {
            return nilTypeReplacement
        }

        return t.Of.String()
    default:
        return t.Name
    }
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *TypeAlias) Kind() TypeKind {
    if t.Of == nil {
        return -1
    }

    return t.Of.Kind()
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *TypeAlias) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *TypeAlias) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || t.Of == nil {
        return false
    }

    return t.Of.Equals(other)
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *TypeAlias) String() string {
    return t.TypeString()
}

/*** BaseType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *BaseType) Size() int {
    switch t.Which {
    case i8typeID, u8typeID:
        return 1
    case i16typeID, u16typeID:
        return 2
    case i32typeID, u32typeID, f32typeID:
        return 4
    case i64typeID, u64typeID, f64typeID:
        return 8
    }

    return 0
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *BaseType) TypeString() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("primitive<%d>", t.Which)
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *BaseType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return BasicKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *BaseType) Id() TypeID {
    return t.Which
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *BaseType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != BasicKind {
        return false
    }

    return t.Which == other.(*BaseType).Which
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *BaseType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return t.Alias
    }

    return t.TypeString()
}

/*** PointerType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *PointerType) Size() int {
    return Unsigned64.Size()
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *PointerType) TypeString() string {
    if t.To == nil {
        return nilTypeReplacement + "&"
    }

    return t.To.String() + "&"
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *PointerType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return PointerKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *PointerType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *PointerType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != PointerKind {
        return false
    }

    return t.To.Equals(other.(*PointerType).To)
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *PointerType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return t.Alias
    }

    return t.TypeString()
}

/*** ArrayType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *ArrayType) Size() int {
    if t.Of == nil {
        return 0
    }

    return t.ElemCount * t.Of.Size()
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *ArrayType) TypeString() string {
    if t.Of == nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s[%d]", nilTypeReplacement, t.ElemCount)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s[%d]", t.Of.String(), t.ElemCount)
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *ArrayType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return ArrayKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *ArrayType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *ArrayType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != ArrayKind {
        return false
    }

    return t.Id() == other.Id()
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *ArrayType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return t.Alias
    }

    return t.TypeString()
}


/*** StructType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *StructType) Size() int {
    if t.Fields == nil {
        return 0
    }

    var size int
    for _, typ := range t.Fields {
        if typ != nil {
            size += typ.Size()
        }
    }

    return size
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *StructType) TypeString() (repr string) {
    if t.Fields == nil || len(t.Fields) == 0 {
        return "struct{}"
    }

    repr += "struct {\n  "
    for _, typ := range t.Fields {
        if typ == nil {
            repr += nilTypeReplacement
        } else {
            repr += typ.String()
        }
        repr += "\n  "
    }

    // Remove the leading spaces on the last type line
    repr = repr[:len(repr)-2]

    return repr + "}"
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *StructType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return StructKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *StructType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *StructType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != StructKind {
        return false
    }

    return t.Id() == other.Id()
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *StructType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return "struct " + t.Alias
    }

    return t.TypeString()
}

/*** EnumType implementation ***/

// Size implements Type
func (t *EnumType) Size() int {
    return Int.Size()
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *EnumType) TypeString() (repr string) {
    if t.Entries == nil || len(t.Entries) == 0 {
        return "enum{}"
    }

    repr = "enum {\n  "

    for name := range t.Entries {
        repr += fmt.Sprintf("%s\n  ", name)
    }

    // Remove 2 trailing whitespaces
    repr = repr[:len(repr)-2]

    return repr + "}"
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *EnumType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return EnumKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *EnumType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *EnumType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != EnumKind {
        return false
    }

    // Can't use other.Id() == t.Id()
    // for enum type strings may vary over time (maps are unordered)

    return reflect.DeepEqual(t.Entries, other.(*EnumType).Entries)
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *EnumType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return "enum " + t.Alias
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("enum <anonymous>[%d]", len(t.Entries))
}

/*** FunctionType implementation ***/

// DefaultFunctionReturnValue is used to determine the return type of functions
// that would miss such annotation
var DefaultFunctionReturnValue = Unit

// Size implements Type
func (t *FunctionType) Size() int {
    return Unsigned64.Size()
}

// TypeString implements Type. It returns the raw string representation of the type
func (t *FunctionType) TypeString() (repr string) {
    if t.Args == nil {
        repr = "()"

        if t.Returns == nil {
            repr += " " + funcTypeArrow + " " + nilTypeReplacement
            return repr
        } else if len(t.Returns.String()) == 0 {
            repr += " " + funcTypeArrow + " " + DefaultFunctionReturnValue.String()
            return repr
        }

        repr += " " + funcTypeArrow + " " + t.Returns.String()
        return strings.TrimSpace(repr)
    }

    repr = "("
    for _, typ := range t.Args {
        if typ != nil {
            repr += typ.String()
        } else {
            repr += nilTypeReplacement
        }
        repr += ", "
    }

    // Cut the trailing coma+space if there were args
    if len(t.Args) > 0 {
        repr = repr[:len(repr)-2]
    }

    repr += ") "
    if t.Returns != nil {
        // Add arrow only if type actually has a type string
        if len(t.Returns.String()) > 0 {
            repr += funcTypeArrow + " "
        }

        repr += t.Returns.String()
    } else {
        repr += funcTypeArrow + " "

        // TODO nil check
        repr += DefaultFunctionReturnValue.String()
    }

    return strings.TrimSpace(repr)
}

// Kind implements Type
func (t *FunctionType) Kind() TypeKind {
    return FunctionKind
}

// Id implements Type. It returns an ID bound to the raw underlying type
func (t *FunctionType) Id() TypeID {
    return hash(t.TypeString())
}

// Equals implements Type
func (t *FunctionType) Equals(other Type) bool {
    if other == nil || other.Kind() != FunctionKind {
        return false
    }

    return t.Id() == other.Id()
}

// String implements fmt.Stringer
func (t *FunctionType) String() string {
    if t.Alias != "" {
        return t.Alias
    }

    return t.TypeString()
}
```

and the second one ...

```
// builtins.go
package virt

var (
    // Unit represents the absence of type (functional-inspired)
    Unit = &UnitType{}

    // Undefined is used to describe symbols which type is not yet known
    Undefined = &UndefinedType{}

    // Unsigned8 represents 1-byte unsigned integers
    Unsigned8 = &BaseType{"u8", u8typeID}

    // Byte represents 1-byte unsigned integers used to hold characters
    Byte = &TypeAlias{"byte", Unsigned8}

    // Unsigned16 represents 2-byte unsigned integers
    Unsigned16 = &BaseType{"u16", u16typeID}

    // Unsigned32 represents 4-byte unsigned integers
    Unsigned32 = &BaseType{"u32", u32typeID}

    // UnsignedInt represents 4-byte unsigned integers (platform dependant)
    UnsignedInt = &TypeAlias{"uint", Unsigned32}

    // Unsigned64 represents 8-byte unsigned integers
    Unsigned64 = &BaseType{"u64", u64typeID}

    // Signed8 represents 1-byte signed integers
    Signed8 = &BaseType{"i8", i8typeID}

    // Signed16 represents 2-byte signed integers
    Signed16 = &BaseType{"i16", i16typeID}

    // Signed32 represents 4-byte signed integers
    Signed32 = &BaseType{"i32", i32typeID}

    // Int represents 4-byte signed integers (platform dependant)
    Int = &TypeAlias{"int", Signed32}

    // Signed64 is an 8-byte signed integer
    Signed64 = &BaseType{"i64", i64typeID}

    // Float64 represents 8-byte floating point numbers
    Float64 = &BaseType{"f64", f64typeID}

    // Float64 represents 4-byte floating point numbers
    Float32 = &BaseType{"f32", f32typeID}

    // String represents strings of characters (C-like strings)
    String = &TypeAlias{"string", &PointerType{"", Byte}}

    // Bool represents the usual boolean values through a 1-byte integer
    Bool = &TypeAlias{"bool", Unsigned8}
)
```

The point of this is to help me (or anyone really) build a solid Type System for whatever program might have use for it (mostly compilers or static analysis tools to be honest).

All types must implement the `Type` interface which should cover anything related to a type really.

Currently implemented type kinds:

- Unit (void)
- Undefined
- Signed / unsigned integers (8, 16, 32, 64)
- Floating point numbers (double, float)
- Pointers (to any other type)
- Arrays (fixed length)
- Structures
- Enums (value less, more as in Java, unlike C)
- Functions (single return value supported yet)

Sorry if this kind of code review is inappropriate, I haven't found a rule / best practices page.

Anyways, thanks for your time!

Comment: The code is _not_ too long. And by linking to the _master_, you violate the rule that the _code should not be changed after an answer is provided_. Therefore you should include the code here. It is still good to keep the links to the repository, though.